# How do I find a file with two keywords and return a date modified in a specific column / row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search a networked drive for files including two keywords. When found, I need them to return the last modified date of said file to the same row one of the keywords was pulled from.
I've found something that is similar to what I need, but it doesn't search for specific keywords.

```
Sub GetFilesDetails()

' in column G= Date Last Modified

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder

Dim myFile As Scripting.File

Dim R as Long

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set myFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(“S:\”)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each myFile In myFolder.Files

       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(R, 7).Value = myFile.DateLastModified

       R = R + 1

Next myFile

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Updated"

End Sub
```

I need keyword 1 to be "Proof" and keyword 2 to be variable based on the column B value. So starting at row 4, Keyword "Proof" and (B4) are the search terms to find the most recent file, and return the last modified date of the file into (G4). From there continue through the rows performing the same task, but skip any row with a blank B cell.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: The keywords will be in the file name. ie "WO67547_Proof1"
Proof is on all of the files that I will be looking for and the WO# is the variable. As long as the only last modified date pulled is the most recent, there shouldn't be more than one occurrence of the WO# and Proof keywords.

[image: I need to search the drive for the WO# and Proof, get the last modified date and input it into the G column. I've been doing this manually and it takes a lot of time.]

Comment: I cannot understand your question... Where the two mentioned "keywords" should be used? Are they part of the file name? Please, edit your question and show us two examples. Then where in the file name they should be found.  "Proof" to be the first? Should there be more then one occurrence using the two keywords?

Comment: Still alive? In order to be helped you should firstly help us understanding what you need...

Comment: What do you mean by **As long as the only last modified date pulled is the most recent, there shouldn't be more than one occurrence of the WO# and Proof keywords**? I did not ask about the occurrences of the two keywords. I asked if a single occurrence of a **file containing the two keywords** exists. So, only one occurrence per file  name for a keywords pair? Then, the first keyword, in order of their position in the file name name is "WO" followed by a number, or only a number and "WO" is something only telling to you anything?

Comment: The keyword pair is not limited to one occurrence. Often times we will have many proof files labeled as such "WO75734_PROOF1" or "WO75734_PROOF3" so a search for the number and Proof may yield multiple occurrences.

"WO" will always be a part of the file name followed by the numbers.

Comment: OK. The last modified date usually is returned as Date + time. Do you need only the date?

Comment: Yes. Date only.

Comment: Do you know the extension of the files to be checked?

Comment: The extension is always .pdf for these files

Comment: OK. I will try preparing an answer.

Comment: Please, test the code I pasted and send some feedback. Please, take care to change `folderPath` variable content, using the folder where the processed files exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code. It extract the matching file names matching each pair of the two keywords and choose the most recent date. The code should be very fast, using arrays. For processing and returning, too:

```
Sub GetFilesDetails()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arrKeys, arrDate, i As Long, fileName As String
  Dim folderPath As String, lastModifDate As Date, lastDate As Date
  Const key2 As String = "Proof"
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary worksheet
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  
  arrKeys = sh.Range("B4:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  arrDate = sh.Range("G4:G" & lastR).Value2
 
  folderPath = "C:/the necessary folder path" 'Use here your real Folder Path!!!
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrKeys)
        If arrKeys(i, 1) <> "" Then
            fileName = Dir(folderPath & "\" & "*" & arrKeys(i, 1) & "*" & key2 & "*.xlsx")
            lastDate = 0
            Do While fileName <> ""
                lastModifDate = CDate(Int(FileDateTime(folderPath & "\" & fileName)))
                If lastModifDate > lastDate Then lastDate = lastModifDate
                fileName = Dir
            Loop
            If lastModifDate <> 0 Then arrDate(i, 1) = lastModifDate: lastModifDate = 0
        End If
  Next i
  
  With sh.Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrDate), 1)
        .Value2 = arrDate
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
  End With
End Sub
```

Do not forget to update `folderPath` with your real folder where the files to be processed exist.

Comment: It looks like its working correctly, but the folder path is always different based on the customer. An example of a full folder path is "S:\Calvary Christian Schools\WO53113_WEBSITE POLE SIGN LETTERING\PROOF" the file name is "CLVRY-WO53113-PROOF1.pdf"  The folder path with always be different after "S:\"

Comment: @Jakebnda Should I understand that this is wrong? Would you expect a piece of code able to know/guess the folder path? Can you supply an algorithm based on what to build the folder path too? Should I also understand that the above code did not answer your question? I am afraid I cannot get you...

Comment: THE CODE WORKS PERFECTLY FOR A SINGLE FOLDER LOCATION. However, I am working with many folder locations. I am looking for the code to search through all folders and subfolders on drive S:\ for these keywords. The file path will always be: Drive > Company(Variable) > WO#(Variable) > PROOF > proof_file.pdf  Should this line then be: ``` fileName = Dir(folderPath & "\" & "*" &  arrKeys(i, 1) & "\" & "*" & "*" & key2 & "*.xlsx")```

Comment: @Jakebnda Did you ask **in your question** to search ""through all folders and subfolders"" of a main folder and I missed that?

Comment: "I'm trying to search a networked drive for files including two keywords." I assumed it was implicit in this sentence, but I am obviously very bad at describing what I need this code to do.

Comment: @Jakebnda I'm afraid that it was not clear at all... A solution for processing such files from all folders and subfolders should be complete redesigned. You cannot return files using wildcard in many places. You can do it only for the file name, for last folder (in a different way, anyhow), but not for a path knowing last folder but using wildcard for an intermediar one... I do  not have enough available time to show you how. Anyhow, it is a different question. Please, place a new question using my above code and ask for a solution **able to do the same for all folders and subfolders**.

Comment: @Jakebnda If you tag me (here, or anywhere), if somebody else did not answer your question when I will be available, I will try my best to design such an answer. I have something in mind. But not iterating between all folders and subfolders...

Comment: @Jakebnda I need a confirmation for one of my suppositions, when designing an answer (of course, if required): It looks logic to me that a folder as "S:\Calvary Christian Schools\WO53113_WEBSITE POLE SIGN LETTERING\PROOF" **should be unique** in order to find a file having `key1 = "53113"` and `key2 = "PROOF"`. Of course, it may keep more then one file containing the two keys in their name. Can you confirm that the above supposition is correct? In parallel with my urgent task I am thinking to an algorithm... I can do it without a unique folder, but the code should be faster if I am right...

Comment: What do you mean by unique in this situation? There will be no other folders sharing the path "S:\Calvary Christian Schools\WO53113_WEBSITE POLE SIGN LETTERING\PROOF". It may keep more than one file with Key1 and Key2 Example: (WO53113_Proof1, WO53113_Proof2, WO53113_Proof3).  Did I answer your question?

Comment: @Jakebnda Like I tried saying: Unique where to find the files containing `key1 = "53113"` and `key2 = "PROOF"` inside their name and the folder, too. I mean, if such a file containing both keys in its name can  be found (even if I cannot understand in which circumstances) In a different folder, let as say, the root one or "S:\Test\", they should not be taken in consideration during the process. Or, is it possible besides "S:\Calvary Christian Schools\WO53113_WEBSITE POLE SIGN LETTERING\PROOF" to exist a folder as "S:\School 2\WO53113_3\PROOF" or "S:\Calvary Christian Schools\WO53113_W1\PROOF"?

Comment: Ah! I see. It is not possible. The WO53113 is unique to the order and the folders/files associated. There will only ever be one folder labeled with key1 on the hard drive. Key1 is to find the "...\WO53113_*\" and key2 is to find the "Proof.pdf" file within the "...\PROOF\" folder. In short, Your supposition is correct. The folder is unique.

Comment: @Jakebnda OK. I have in my had a scenario to be applied... The code would be simpler if no such a unicity, but the code will take more time. I am thinking to  firstly place all pdf files from folders and subfolders in an array and then processing each such full name against the necessary conditions. If no such a unique subfolder, the iteration will take place for all existing such files full name. Confirming my supposition, I can make the code exiting the big array loop, after processing the files in that specific subfolder... Will you place such a question? I will leave my office in 30 mins.

Comment: @Jakebnda If you create the question until I leave, please tag me here. I will try doing something. Otherwise, I will be able to see it after some hours when I will be at home. Without that, i cannot keep the step with the new questions appearing. Or somebody else will answer your question until I will be available, eventually..

Comment: QUestion Posted!

Comment: This code just broke for some reason. It's saying there is a type mismatch and highlights "If arrKeys(i, 1) <> "" Then"   It was working just fine until today..

Comment: @Jakebnda Nothing is broken by itself, I am afraid. If you did not adapt the code, even with a small modification, or the used data in the processed range is not different, the code should work in the same way for ever... If you now use **numbers instead of strings** as keys, for instance, try using `If CStr(arrKeys(i, 1)) <> "" Then`, in order to convert it as `String`... When VBA places the cells in the array, it uses the found type in the respective cell. I (only) think this may be your problem. If my suggestion does not solve it, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? I need seeing.

Comment: That worked. haha Thank you! Turns out one of the other people editing the sheet put "Multiple WOs" in the keys column...  /sigh haha

Comment: Im going to need your Discord info or something. You are a life saver!